# Javascript to Search In Multiple Tables in same page

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make this to work with multiple diferent tables? I tought if I changed the id in the tables and in the javascript would made that work, but it didn't.

And for the first table I have this:

```
<table id="table" class="table paginated table-hover no-wrap">
```

Javascript:

```
var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

And I was doing this, try to make it work in other tables

```
<table id="table2" class="table paginated table-hover no-wrap">
```

Javascript:

```
var $rows = $('#table2 tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

To make the search I use this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="search" type="text">
</div>
```

If I remove the second javascript, the first will work.

Comment: You can select tables by class instead. `$('.table tbody tr')`

Comment: @Mohammad I tried that but if I search in one table, the other will output the result of my search but witth the content of that table, And if i try to search in the second table, doesent work.

Comment: It work in http://jsfiddle.net/690713m4/

Comment: @Mohammad I wanted to diferent search places, 1 for the first table, and the second for the second table

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/690713m4/1/

Comment: It did the job thx